# Phase listener in composite component not called ever

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, phaselistener

I have a composite component:

```xml
<cc:interface componentType="com.example.MyComponent">
    <!-- ... -->
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <f:phaseListener binding="#{cc}"/>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

And its class:

```java
@FacesComponent("com.example.MyComponent")
public class MyComponent extends UIOutput implements NamingContainer, PhaseListener
{
    @Override
    public String getFamily()
    {
        return "javax.faces.NamingContainer";
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId()
    {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        // Do something ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

Neither the `beforePhase(PhaseEvent)` nor `afterPhase(PhaseEvent)` methods are called in any case, be it a full or partial page load.

I note this bug here: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1200, but it seems to have been fixed quite a while ago.

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 on Java 6u33 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#{cc}` is re-evaluated everytime when the `beforePhase()` or `afterPhase()` method of the `<f:phaseListener>` actually needs to be executed by the `UIViewRoot`. The `#{cc}` is not available in the EL scope at that moment. It's only available within the component's scope.

It works fine if the `binding` points to at least a request scoped variable like as follows in the composite component's constructor:

```
public MyComponent() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("ccc", this);
}
```

with

```html
<f:phaseListener binding="#{ccc}" />
```

This construct only fails if you've multiple composite components of this type, of course.

You'd better look for an alternate approach: get rid of the `<f:phaseListener>` altogether and just use [`UIViewRoot#addPhaseListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#addPhaseListener%28javax.faces.event.PhaseListener%29) in the composite component's constructor:

```
public MyComponent() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().addPhaseListener(this);
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, better use [`UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html#COMPONENT_FAMILY) constant instead of hardcoding `"javax.faces.NamingContainer"`.

Comment: Ugh... And I thought I was getting on top of this lifecycle stuff. Yes, it works and it's clean enough. Thanks for the extra tip as well. It's just the constant I was looking for.